# bash - how to append text after the 2nd line of a xml file?

Tags: xml, linux, bash

I have a directory with around 150 subfolders. Each of them contains a *.xml file. Now, I want to append a multiple-line text, starting after the 2nd line in all those xmls.
I know works with sed command, but how do I actually do that?

Comment: XML structure is defined by elements, attributes, etc., not lines. Use an XML-aware tool.

Comment: Can you show us how your files look like? (Just edit your question) Adding something in an XML file might corrupt the XML syntax.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot post here, since this confidential, but what I want to append is just  another xml content

<?xml version='1.1' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!--some xml content here-->

Answer (score 1):

with sed to insert a text after the specified second line `2a\`. `-i` option to edit file in place

```
sed -i "2a\\$text" file.txt
```

Comment: This is not POSSIX compliant. The above is a GNU sed extension.

Answer (score 0):

With AWK you can do:

```
var="some text"

awk -v a="$var" 'NR != 1{ print $0, a}' file.xml
```

This one, append text in the end of each line after the second line of file. But I'm not sure if this is want you want really